# Google-Plus error +1ing on pages with embedded video

Tags: video, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm using the html 5 tag to embed the google plus 1 button on my site

`<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"></div>`

It works fine for all pages except when there's a video embedded on the page. I get a generic button error (no good log that I can see in the network traffic) and then the button redirects to : https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1199142?p=plusone_button_error&rd=1

It's all pretty simply setup so I'm having difficulty locking the problem down.

---

Here's an example of a page on which the error occurs: http://www.trendhunter.com/keynote/enlightening-keynote

Here is an example of a page on which the button appears to work fine:
http://www.trendhunter.com/trends/glutinous-fast-foods-mcdonalds-china-offers-the-new-sausage-double-beef-bur

I'm using this script to load in gplus:

(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();

I am loading in the html for the button in a .load afterwards, I moved the google plus script to the callback for the .load but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is not rendering because the Google proxy can't reach the page.  Because your other button is working, with the href param passed, this means that the page has a bad canonical tag / is somehow blocking the Google+ proxy.  To test the page without having to write any HTML, try just sharing the link directly in Google+:

http://www.trendhunter.com/keynote/enlightening-keynote

If done in G+, you will notice that Google+ can't find the page for sharing. In other words, your +1 code is fine, the issue is that your page isn't being discovered by Google+. The quickest/easiest fix this is going to be linking to a page that can be rendered because this is probably a problem on the Google+ side.

A quick look at your noscript tag led me to this link:

http://www.trendhunter.com/keynote/enlightening-keynote?ModPagespeed=noscript

Which **DOES** render for Google+.  Perhaps passing that as your href to the button will fix it!

Comment: That's a different google plus button. I'm talking about the one on the left sidebar (Relative to the article) that loads afterwards. It is using the newer HTML compatible code and that's the one I'm having the error on.

Comment: Got it, just saw that.  Does removing the href section help?

Comment: There's no href section on the html5 one that im using

   `<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"></div>`

Comment: Hmm.  You could try explicit load, I'll dig deeper and see if there's anything else that could be the culprit here.

Comment: I attempted the explicit load and while it did work as explicit load should, it did nothing to solve the issue with embeded video articles

Comment: Another update :( It looks like your code is working, the issue is that Google+ can't see your page. This is a good bit tougher to debug, I'll keep seeing what can be done here.

Comment: ModPagespeed=noscript parameter totally worked. Can you quickly walk me through how you came to that? I guess I'm not sure what you meant by looking at the noscript tag.

Comment: I'm not really sure I want to keep the links with ModPagespeed at the end of them. Is there another way to fix this ?

Comment: The issue is that the Google+ proxy is having trouble seeing the content on your page when pagespeed is running. Pagespeed seems to give Google+ issues. There can be a number of reasons for this, in most cases it happens when the page is difficult to parse, has dense JavaScript, or relies heavily on JavaScript. I'll be sure to update the response if I can come up with a better solution. When you pass the parameter to pagespeed, it disables whatever feature is causing the G+ proxy from being able to read / render the page content.

Comment: It's alright for now but I figure if that link is disabling some pagespeed services then anyone following that link (which is the intent on g+) is going to be losing some to a lot of benefits of the pagespeed service, if my assumptions on how that link works is correct.